# React Native Android - taps on inputs don't do anything

Tags: android, react-native, react-android

I'm getting strange behavior on Android where my taps on TextInputs and Buttons are not doing anything. On the TextInputs I see the little text cursor flash for a millisecond. It happens on both a Huawei P8 physical phone and a Samsung Galaxy S6 virtual device. iOS works perfectly.

There are no errors in the developer console, however I do have to install the app on the phone like this: `$ adb install android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk` otherwise it says "failed to install all". I don't think this is related because I have always been installing it that way and I haven't had this issue in the past.

It might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836568/react-native-textinput-prevents-taps-on-screen) but it has no answer.

Any ideas why the taps on `TextInputs` and `Buttons` don't seem to do anything on Android? The fact it works on iOS makes me think it isn't code related.

Comment: We need more information. Like your code. Ideally a simplified test case on snack - http://snack.expo.io/

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure which part of the code was causing it. So I deleted components until the app worked. I had an extra closing curly brace `}` in the JSX of one of my components. Interesting that iOS worked and Android didn't.